# How to use MS Word to create html that displays correctly on windows and linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, http-headers

When I create a document with MS Word and upload it to an html server it it correctly displayed when it is a windows server, but not when it is a linux server.
I tried this with both IE and Firefox.
The meta tag in the source says charset=windows-1252
Displaying the source code in the browser shows exactly the same source as I uploaded, so the server is not changing that. Nevertheless are characters like accented e displayed as silly characters when obtained from the linux server.
So somewhere in the tcp/http/??? records that the server sends to the browser makes the browser interpret the characters different from what is ment.
What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a document in MS Word, there are a lot of characters that you can't see that are actually in the file, such as end of line markers, page breaks, etc. which you will not notice until after you upload the file to the server.

You should always use a plain text editor such as Notepad++, or even bluefish to create these files. Sometimes you can get MSWord to do the trick if you make sure to save the file as a web document(htm or html), but the special characters will usually begin to cause problems depending on your goal.

Comment: I know the trick to use Notepad as an intermediate editor to get rid of all unwated formatting. But my question is about the situation that I want the formatting in the html. But the special chars are changed.